# VSCode: Could not find conda environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, git-bash

I set up to run Conda commands in my Git Bash, and made sure that a conda environment is installed in one of the `envs_dirs` directory. But I am now having trouble on finding conda environment, and guessing that it is because of the wrong argument of the source command. Its an env location instead of the env name. However, I couldn't figure out how to change the argument, essentially couldn't locate from where this source command run automatically once I start a new git bash in VSC.

```
$ source C:/Programs/Miniconda3_x64/Scripts/activate **P:\Programs\envs\py39**
Could not find conda environment: P:Programsenvspy39
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.
```

I wish to switch **"P:\Programs\envs\py39"** with "py39".

Many thanks in advance.

How and where to change the source command argument